# Why does pumount close a luks device it did not open?

Tags: debian, mount, encryption, luks

I have a luks device and it is opened on boot by /etc/crypttab. lsblk looks like this:

```
sdc                                             8:32   1 114,6G  0 disk  
└─luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c   253:2    0 114,6G  0 crypt
```

I pmount the device like this:

```
pmount /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c
```

I unmount it like this (both work):

```
pumount /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c
pumount /media/mapper_luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c
```

But after pumount lsblk looks like this:

```
sdc                                             8:32   1 114,6G  0 disk
```

Why did pumount close the luks device? From the man page of pumount it says:

```
Normally, pumount will not luksClose (see cryptsetup(1)) a device pmount did not open.
```

The luks device was opened by /etc/crypttab on boot and not by pmount! Why does pumount close the luks device? Is this a bug?

I am on debian bullseye.

Comment: How does it even know who opens what? If it makes a decision according to the naming scheme, see if the behavior changes by setting a custom name for this LUKS device.

Comment: Oh never mind, it's probably something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note:* I'm completely unfamiliar with `pumount`, and I don't even have a Debian install available for testing, so [I just grabbed the source code from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/pmount) and making wild assumptions based on what I found in there…

`pumount` has an option, `--luks-force` to close LUKS devices it did not open (as you already quoted from the manpage).

However from the source code, there seems to be a mistake in the implementation.

So in `pumount.c` there is this bit of option parsing:

```
int luks_force = 0;
[...]
       { "luks-force", 0, NULL, 'L'},
[...]
            case 'L':        luks_force = 1; break;
```

...and that's it! The option sets the `luks_force = 1` variable. Otherwise it's initialized as 0.

But it doesn't matter one bit at all since... that variable isn't used anywhere.

In `luks.c` there is this bit of code:

```
void
luks_release( const char* device, int force )
{
  if(force || luks_has_lockfile(device)) {
    spawnl( CRYPTSETUP_SPAWN_OPTIONS,
            CRYPTSETUP, CRYPTSETUP, "luksClose", device, NULL );
    luks_remove_lockfile(device);
[...]
```

So it will `luksClose` if either a lockfile is present, or if `force` is true.

And this function is called by `pumount.c` like this:

```
/* release LUKS device, if appropriate */
luks_release( device, 1 );
```

So there you go, no matter what you do, `force` is always set to 1, and so it closes the LUKS device.

That last line is probably where it should be using the `luks_force` variable instead of 1.

Comment: What is the right place to report this bug?

Comment: the debian package page I linked above also has a link to the debian bug tracker -  https://bugs.debian.org/pmount - so please report it there, I guess

Comment: in general, pmount seems rather dated, [no active development in 10 years](https://alioth-archive.debian.org/releases/pmount/pmount/) other than minor patches for typos and the like, there's nothing going on with this package. so perhaps also consider using something else entirely...

Comment: Is pmount a debian project?

Comment: pretty much... I found a fork of it on github https://github.com/MisterDA/pmount and it seems they found the same problem and... [simply removed it altogether](https://github.com/MisterDA/pmount/commit/201a518bc20da581a615b8be11ce8d3cf83004f3) instead of applying a simple fix. But something else seems to have happened before that as it no longer even has the luks_force variable at that point. Sorry, I don't have time to read into the commit history there, and it's not the branch that Debian uses anyway, so whatever is going on there doesn't help you either...

Comment: ...and the author of that github project himself states that his [current version is broken](https://github.com/MisterDA/pmount/issues/2#issuecomment-823902922), so that's a dead end also. So reporting it with Debian seems to be your best bet. That or just patch it yourself...