# How to mount an ext4 partition as user now that pmount is dead under Debian?

Tags: debian, mount, ext4

I am using Debian Bullseye. In [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726626/why-does-pumount-close-a-luks-device-it-did-not-open) I was told that `pmount` is dead (see comments of accepted answer).

I encountered bugs when using it and so I want to use something else.

What is the best alternative to `pmount` on Debian? It would be great if there was a tool in the official apt repository.

The mapper file /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c is created by /etc/crypttab and it's an ext4 partition. I want to mount it read/write as user. On unmount it is important that the mapper file does not get closed (luksClose).

Answer (score 0):

`udisksctl mount --device /dev/mapper/luks-672dcc74-d002-47dc-b61b-525baf91dc7c` serves that purpose. I haven't tried on debian, but I have a little shell script that uses udisksctl to mount an encrypted LVM volume, which I keep on an unencrypted volume on an external hard drive for backup reasons. So, I think it does not close the luks device, because I need to do that separately.

Comment: I have no option --device but only --block-device. When I do this it opens a window asking for the root password. So this does not work.

Comment: huh! That's how it works for me, but I'm not on debian.